Is there an English equivalent to the Hindi proverb, "A washerman's dog belongs neither at home nor at the riverbank"?
Consider this famous Hindi proverb,

A washerman's dog belongs neither at home nor at the riverbank.

This saying is used to describe someone who doesn't fully belong to or fit into any group or place, often because they are trying to serve or please multiple parties and end up satisfying none.
Is there a English equivalent to this proverb?
I should also point out that in US (at least) most people do their own laundry (based on my brief experience there) so probably there is no washerman there.

We had washerwomen in the West before domestic washing machines became common!

@KateBunting One (famous/controversial) economist said that washing machine is man's greatest invention. :)

I think the expectation in the proverb is that the dog is a working animal that is not suited for the task of hauling the clothing and being a working animal is not considered a house pet. If that adds anything to an english conversion.

@Eric Because the birth control pill was funded by a woman.

I suggest nothing like that crops up anywhere or when in English… unless, of course, by direct translation.
Searching for clues, has the fact of the dog being a washerman's anything to do with caste which, for good or bad, might cloud any translation?

@Barmar I am sorry, I did not understand the point you are making. How is washing machine connected to birth control pills?

@Eric They both save women enormous amounts of time. One is "man's greatest invention", the other is "woman's greatest invention".

@Eric — in the US we have dry-cleaners.  Dry-cleaning is not dry, it just uses solvents other than water (typically perchloroethylene), and most dry-cleaners will also do ordinary, water-based laundry, but as it’s a smaller part of their business, they don’t change their name.

Another possibility: Neither fish nor fowl.
Merriam-Webster defines this as:

one that does not belong to a particular class or category.
The movie is neither fish nor fowl—it's not really a comedy, but it's too light-hearted to be called a drama.


Vote this is the answer. It's the answer I came here to write.

I considered including this in my answer, but decided that I probably wouldn't use it to describe a person's behaviour.

@JessFuckett — ditto.

Here are a few possibilities:

Here's an idiom:

You can't serve two masters.


There's a quote by John Lydgate that's frequently cited:

You can please some of the people all of the time, you can please all of the people some of the time, but you can’t please all of the people all of the time.


A little off-topic, but there's a nickname for someone who does an OK job at many things, but can't do anything really well:

A jack of all trades and a master of none.




John Lydgate was born in the 14th century.

@TimR — that attribution is floating around the Internet, but it’s patently false.

I would normally expect the first idiom to be in the form "No man can serve two masters" or "A man can't serve two masters".

@aantia Any of the three are fine. Mine is just less formal than yours.

Whether correctly attributed or not, the 'Lydgate' quote appears to be the inspiration for the chorus of the Rick Nelson song Garden Party; "You can't please everyone, so you've got to learn to please yourself."

I knew the quote but not the author, so I did a Google search. You can see from the link the in answer where the attribution comes from.

You could use the expression "falling between two stools". It means that something tries to satisfy two different sets of requirements, and so fails to satisfy either.

Related to "servant of two masters"

@Barmar I've never heard the "servant of two masters" whereas "falling between two stools" crops up a lot. This NGram graph backs up my opinion.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=servant+of+two+masters%2Cfalling+between+two+stools%2C+falls+between+two+stools&year_start=1500&year_end=1950&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3

I may have been thinking of the proverb from the Bible "No man can serve two masters."

This is so completely wrong - hard to understand the upvotes.  This has nothing to do with requirements - it has to do with belonging

@SK I think that my answer is completely relevant to this part of the OP's explanation: "because they are trying to serve or please multiple parties and end up satisfying none"

One correction I would like to make, the proverb is "Dhobi ka katka" not "Dhobi ka kutta". "Katka" refers to wooden plank/board on which launderers wash clothes, whereas "kutta" refers to a dog. So, proverb becomes, "The washerman's wooden plank/board belongs neither at home nor at the riverbank." The planks were heavy and taking it from home to riverbank and vice versa was exhausting which is why the boards were often hidden somewhere along the way near the riverbank. As for the equivalent in English, there are numerous possible answers already submitted.

This provides invaluable information, and clarification, which explains the origin of the proverb and makes a lot more sense. I just wonder how accurate your account is, but +1 from me all the same.

I am a native speaker; It is actually dog not what you said. Not sure how you got your info.

Could easily see a proverb originating organically as "katka" and then phonetically simplifying, while still remaining semantically plausible, to "kutta". Such reanalysis often happens with proverbs and idioms, especially a few centuries later when the original cultural context has been lost to the majority of speakers. It would be an eggcorn that gains enough acceptance to be a valid alternative. But I'm just speculating in the case of this proverb.

This seems like it could be true, but many phrases and idioms have multiple conflicting etymologies. To support this you should provide a citation from an authoritative source such as a dictionary or scholarly article.

It sounds like the dog's existence is (considered) pointless, if not harmful - providing no tangible benefit to its owner in exchange for the cost of keeping it. In this sense, the phrase "just another mouth to feed" might actually be relevant, especially if the owner is struggling to support themselves. Another expression in this vein is "white elephant", referring to a possession that costs more to keep than it's worth. Or you could call it a "lapdog" to emphasize its owner keeps it solely for their own pleasure or entertainment, usually implying that it's worth little otherwise.

It's funny you mentioned lapdog. I actually don't know what that means (I know it is a kind of dog, but why lap etc.?). I actually had a friend Labrador and Australian Collie. I wonder how they feel about the lapdog thing as opposed to Dog With A Job?

A lapdog is a dog small and calm enough to comfortably sit on your lap. While in the literal sense, any small dog can be a lapdog, the term is often is pejoratively used to describe over-bred pets of aristocrats who have, over generations, been given exaggerated features that would make them incapable of doing work, even if their owner wanted to train them for it.

Right. When applied to a person, the implication is that they receive more favor than they deserve from leadership, i.e. that their position is the result of favoritism rather than merit.
